# Excel: need help with unusual lookup function (sorted column is different from lookup column)

Tags: excel, lookup, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I am having trouble constructing a unusual lookup formula in Excel.

Normally, I would use VLOOKUP(), but the pitfall is that I want to look up a number in a column from a table that is sorted on *an other* column. Vlookup can only lookup things on the sorted column itself.

**The scenario** is as follows:

- The table is sorted ascending on column B.
- For a given parameter P, I now want to find the first A value, starting from the top and going down, that is bigger than or equal to that parameter P.
- The function should then return the corresponding B value.

Table(part off, the complete table is much bigger):

```
    A      B
1  640    4.5
2  1600   7.0
3  640    7.5
4  1280   12.0
5  1920   16.5
6  2560   21.0
7  1600   19.8
8  3200   26.8
9  4800   33.8
```

**For example**, say my parameter is 1100, then I want my formula to return 7.0, because the first entry when searching downwards in column A that is bigger than or equal to 1100 is 1600, which has a corresponding B value of 7.0

I've tried my luck with [Array Formula's](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArrayFormulas.aspx) (also known as "ctrl-shift-enter formula's") and constructed something like this:

```
{=INDEX(table;
        MATCH(MIN(IF(columnA-$C1>=0;columnA;FALSE));
              IF(columnA-$C1>=0;columnA;FALSE);
              0);
        2)}
```

with *C1* containing my parameter, *table* the range  A1:B9, and *columnA* the range B1:B9

But that doesn't work (in the example above, it returns 12.0 because 1280 is selected by the MIN() function) .

**Solution I don't want to use:**
I could write some VBA could to go through the table, but I don't want to do that (because of annoying 'macro warnings', and because Excel on Mac doesn't support VBA anymore)

Anybody any clues?

Comment: If it were I, I would probably try to use a Pivot table or use MS Access to query the data since they handle "query stuff" and data aggregation much better. However, perhaps that's not the type of solution you're looking for.

Comment: @Ben: no indeed. Pivot Table are very useful but I find them a bit tricky when you don't use them daily (as is the case for me). And i want to keep the solution/problem in one program, no need for Access :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
{=INDEX(B1:B9,MIN(IF(A1:A9>C1,ROW(A1:A9),FALSE)))}
```

Note that I am using English UK language settings - you will have to alter the formula to match your locale, replacing commas with semi-colons, etc.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution got me going. I had to add small correction to support my table not starting at the first row. I changed it to {=INDEX(B1:B9,MIN(IF(A1:A9>C1,ROW(A1:A9),FALSE))-ROW(A1:A9)+1)} which is now working fine. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't want an array formula you could try =OFFSET($C$5,MATCH($A$17,B5:B13),0) where C5 is the start of you B column, B5:B13 is you A column and A17 is you value to match against.

Ninja edit: Here is a version which works for the less-than or **equal-to** bit of your specification.
=OFFSET($C$5,IF(ISNA(MATCH($A$17,B5:B13,0)), IF(ISNA(MATCH($A$17,B5:B13)),0,MATCH($A$17,B5:B13)), MIN(MATCH($A$17,B5:B13,0)-1,MATCH($A$17,B5:B13))),0)

Comment: If possible I indeed would rather not use array formulas. But unfortunately, the formula doesn't work because of the way that MATCH() works. Two problems: (a) it doesn't give a value for a value below the first A value in the list, (b) it gives the next value when a value matches an item in the A column. 
Thanks for the effort though !!

Comment: Wow, quick update. However, I've gone with AdamRalph's solution already. Didn't check your ninja-edit since it requires a lot of brain exercise :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data table is in range A2:B10, with the value you're searching on in cell B1, the following seems to work:

```
 =IF(B1<A2,B2,IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B1,$A$2:$B$10,2,FALSE)),INDEX(B2:B10,MATCH(B1,A2:A10)+1),VLOOKUP(B1,$A$2:$B$10,2,FALSE)))
```

I edited this to account for when the lookup value is smaller than any of the values in the list.

Comment: Thanks for the effort! As I've explained in avid's post, that is indeed a problem.